# Request Post CI

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to know open cart uses a $this->request->post['redirect'] what would be the same in codeigniter $this->input->get_post() or $this->input->get()

Don't understand the inputs well yet on user guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For post:

`$this-> input-> post ('');`